# What is the usage of 所 here?

Tags: grammar

「我於五受陰觀察非我、非我所，而非阿羅漢者，我於我慢、我欲、我使，未斷、未知、未離、未吐。」

The above is translated by a Ven. Anālayo as "‘I examine these five aggregates of clinging as not self and not belonging to the self, yet I am not an arahant, with the influxes being eradicated. I have not yet abandoned the ‘I am’ conceit, the desire [related to the notion] ‘I am’, and the underlying tendency towards ‘I am’, have not yet [fully] understood it, not yet become sepa­rated from it, not yet vomited it out.’”

If possible, I would like to know how 所 in 非我所 implies "and not belonging to the self"?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%88%91%E6%89%80%E5%9F%B7):

> 我所包括我的财富资产、我的眷属(父母、伴侣、子女、亲友)、我的成就、我的世间智慧能力、我的名声等。
>
> 我所：意指“我的所有”。

我所 means 我的所有 or *my everything* or *anything that belongs to me*.
非 means *not*, thus 非我所 implies *not belonging to me*

Answer (score 2):

我所 is the short form of 我所有.

Sanskrit: ममकारः mamakāraḥ

> 《丁福保：佛學大辭典》 （Ding Fubao's Dictionary of Buddhist Studies）
>   「我所有」之略。
>   自身為「我」，自身外之萬物謂為「我所有」。

The world can be devided to two parts.
One part is 我, self, and the other one is 我所有, everything else except self.

> 《Soothill-Hodous Dictionary of Chinese Buddhist Terms》
>   我所有; 我所事
>   Mine, personal, subjective;
>   personal conditions, possessions, or anything related to the self.

Answer (score 0):

◎ 所 suǒ
〈形〉
(1) 一切,所有 [all]。如:所事(亦作“所是”。凡事,事事);所有品(所占有的东西);所是(所有)

so, 所 means possession here.